# Parsing json object in javascript with an empty property name

Tags: javascript, json

If I have the json object below... how can I access the string "Passwords must have...".

The "" property name name inside the ModelState is confusing me.

Thanks!

```
{
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
        "": [
            "Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character. Passwords must have at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z')."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `testsome["ModelState"][""]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a={
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
"ModelState": {
    "": [
        "Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character. Passwords must have at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z')."
    ]
}
};
console.log(a.ModelState[""]);
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: a slight improvement: for (var i = 0; i < a.ModelState[''].length; i++) alert(a.ModelState[''][i]);

Answer (score 1):

Like so

```js
var data = {
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
        "": [
            "Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character. Passwords must have at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z')."
        ]
    }
};

console.log(data.ModelState['']);
```

Answer (score 0):

````
var a = {
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
        "": [
            "Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character. Passwords must have at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z')."
        ]
    }
}

var yourAnswer = a.ModelState[""];```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it this way:

```
var somedata = {
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
        "": [
            "Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character. Passwords must have at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z')."
        ]
    }
};
console.log(somedata["ModelState"][""]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_dict = {
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
        "": [
            "Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character. Passwords must have at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z')."
        ]
    }
}
var my_string = my_dict['ModelState'][''][0]
```

this works for me